# Layout não aparece quando programa é executado

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Estou testando um código e coloquei um `button` e uma `picture box` no `windows form` porém, quando vou executar não é mostrado o `button` e `picture box` que coloquei. Verifiquei e a propriedade `Visible` está como `true`. Tentei em Visual Studio C# 2008 e 2005. O que pode ser? Segue imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No constructor do seu `form` invoca o método `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: Não tinha colocado! Na verdade copiei o código de novo e nem percebi que estava faltando. Sou iniciante e essas coisas ainda passam despercebidas. Muito obrigada!!